# Why is the Knife Tool so Finicky?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, knife-tool

So many times I try to use the knife tool and it simply won't grab anything. I move the screen around randomly and zoom in and out and if I'm lucky it will eventually start working. See gif for example. This one actually worked pretty quickly. Other times I have to try for such an extended period of time that It's hardly even worth trying to use. Is it me, or is it some kind of bug?

[image: knife]

Comment: Please report a bug, this is an actively maintained area - if you find some problem we need a blend so we can redo the error, but the bug tracker is best for this.